# Wie übersetzt man "deductive system"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Wie übersetzt man "[deductive system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deductive_system)" von Englischen ins Deutsche?

> A deductive system (also called a deductive apparatus of a formal system) consists of the axioms (or axiom schemata) and rules of inference that can be used to derive the theorems of the system.

Quelle: Wikipedia-Artikel zu "[deductive system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deductive_system)"

- Deduction: Ableitung, Folgerung, ... ([leo](http://dict.leo.org/?lp=ende&search=deduction))
- System: System

Comment: Man übersetzt die Einzelwörter und zieht sie zusammen: "Ableitungssystem" - wie immer. Oder behält das Latein bei "deduktives System". Wo ist das Problem?

Comment: @userunknown: Das stimmt halt nicht immer. Beispiel: Kindergarten != Childrens Garden

Comment: Wir reden ja auch nicht über das Rückübersetzen - erstens - und zweitens ist Kindergarten kein keine Kombination sachlicher Termini wie es Rostengarten wäre, und da würde es wiederum funktionieren. Ich stimme aber zu, dass die Methode nicht immer funktioniert - sie funktioniert aber in den meisten Fällen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In der Mathematik/Logik [Kalkül](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalk%C3%BCl)

Comment: Meistens ist das englische Vokabular reicher an Nuancen, Semi-Synonymen und Alternativen (wegen seiner bewegten Geschichte). Aber manchmal hat das Deutsche das perfekte, kurze und genau treffende Wort. Dies hier ist so ein Wort.

Comment: Aber "Kalkül" stimmt nur, wenn "theorems" wirklich Sätze im Sinne der Logik meint. Was es bei "deductive system" nicht immer tut. Wie gesagt, Kontext fehlt.

Answer (score 0):

Ich kenne "Deduktionsregeln", das schließt (je nach Definition) manchmal die Axiome mit ein (als Regeln mit leerer Voraussetzung). "Ableitungsregeln" gibt es alternativ auch.

"Deduktionssystem" gibt es auch, klingt aber eher nach Gewaltübersetzung. Ich persönlich würde - je nach Kontext - einfach "Deduktionsregeln" oder "System von Deduktionsregeln" oder so etwas nehmen.

[Formales System](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formales_System) habe ich auch schon gehört, das ist aber etwas allgemeiner.

Mit Angabe des Kontexts könnte man bessere Vorschläge machen. :-)

Comment: Formales System ist es sicher nicht. Wie würdest du sonst den Beispielsatz übersetzen? (Der Beispielsatz gibt einen Kontext an: Lambda-Kalkül bzw. Mathematik bzw. Theoretische Informatik)

Comment: @moose: Falls du mit dem Beispielsatz den gelb unterlegten Teil meinst: Ich würde ihn gar nicht übersetzen, ohne zuerst den restlichen Kontext zu kennen. Um Lambda-Kalkül geht es sicher nicht, die Reduktionsregeln im Lambda-Kalkül sehen anders aus (obwohl man sie als formales System definieren kann). Und "Mathematik" bzw. "Theor. Informatik" ist klar, aber zu allgemein.

Comment: Ok, ich dachte es wäre offensichtlich, dass der Link darüber die Quelle ist (also der englische Wiki-Artikel "deductive System")